# Removing item from knockout observableArray is causing exception in jquery-validation

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jquery validation combined with knockoutjs. I am binding to an observableArray and using a checkbox in the template. When the checkbox is unchecked the item is removed from the observableArray. After this happens an exception occurs "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null" that is coming from jquery validation. To see this exception you can use the chrome developer tools to watch.

Here is a jsfiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/dgHS3/28/

Here is the html

```
<form id="myForm">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Use</th>
            <th>Caption</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: selectedFields">
        <tr > 
            <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected, uniqueName: true, click: $root.addRemoveField" /></td>
            <td><input class="required" data-bind="value: Caption, enable: IsSelected, uniqueName: true" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function FieldData(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Caption = ko.observable(data.Caption);
    self.IsSelected = ko.observable(data.IsSelected);
}

function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedFields = ko.observableArray([]);


    init = function () {
        var data = new Object();

        data.Caption = "cap1";
        data.IsSelected = true;

        var flds = [];
        var fld = new FieldData(data);
        flds.push(fld);

        self.selectedFields(flds);

    }();

    self.addRemoveField = function (field) {
        if (field.IsSelected()) {
            self.selectedFields.push(field);
        }
        else {
            self.selectedFields.remove(field);
        }

        return true;
    };

}

var vm = new myViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```